# Custom launcher.ini in export of Eclipse RCP product

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to tell the Eclipse Product export wizard to add a custom launcher.ini (the "eclipse.ini" deployed with my RCP application) in the export instead of the generated one (the wizard generates it from the content of the "Launching" tab section "Program Arguments" or "VM Arguments")?

Background of my question: I need different launcher options when starting the RCP application inside of Eclipse IDE during development and when starting it stand-alone outside the IDE. If I put the options needed when starting the application outside of the IDE in the "Launching" section of the product file, then this is fine for the stand-alone RCP application, but since Eclipse IDE generates the launch configuration for debuggging or running the RCP application from the product file these options do not fit during development.

If I change the generated launch configuration then Eclipse IDE overwrites these changes the next time I click "Launch an Eclipse application" in the "Testing" section of the Product Configuration Editor.

So I thought it would be nice if I could specify a custom launcher.ini in the "product export wizard" (the way like specifying the custom config.ini on the "Configuration" tab of the Product Configuration Editor) but unfortunately there isn't such an option in Eclipse Luna SR2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't customize the ini used in the exported RCP.

You can change the options used when you test your RCP from Eclipse.

Instead of using the 'Launch and Eclipse application' option in the product file use the 'Run > Run Configurations...' menu. An entry from your Eclipse application should already have been created there, you can modify it as you require.

Comment: I already thought about modifying the generated run configuration, but it has the drawback that if I change the product (e.g. remove/add plugins) I have to manually sync the run configuration. But since it is not possible to customize the ini used in the export, I will use this solution. Thanks!